# What is the correct way to authenticate a player with password from Unity to a php api server?

Tags: unity, php, mysql, authentication

So, I have a game in Unity for mobiles that gives you the possibility to sign-up with username, email and password to unlock extra features.
The datas are sent, through a POST request, to a PHP+MYSQL server that expose an API. I'm developing both so I have complete freedom on how to implement it.

My question is what is the correct way to:

- save auth data on player mobile device so it can automatically login
  on subsequent runs of the game
- how to safely send username and password to my server for the authentication

I want to protect data from man in the middle attacks and I don't want to send clear password because users tends to always use the same email/password combination.

Thank you

Comment: This is subjective. For the love of your players, though: transmit securely and don't store in plaintext.

Comment: I'm asking for the correct way to do this within Unity and towards a PHP API.

Answer (score 3):

You want your webserver access to go through HTTPS; that will encrypt the traffic so people in the middle can't read it.

Comment: Yes, but it requires me a Signed Certificate from a Third Party (not self signed) and I don't think that Unity is capable of generating an encrypted POST.
Please don't give me general advices but specific implementation with Unity and PHP web server. Thank you

Comment: You are vulnerable without HTTPS. I'm just calling it like it is. Implementing your own security would A) be insecure B) take a very long time. Our Unity game goes over HTTPS, and it works fine. As far as my personal projects, I'm at a webhost that does HTTPS for me. They do myproject.secure.hostcompany.com, and they have a shared certificate for secure.hostcompany.com that their subscribers can use without extra charge.

Comment: Did using https with Unity in your iOS build give you problems with App Store approval? (they ask you you use encryption)

Comment: No trouble with Apple at all.